# Bringing UIManagedDocument to OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsdocument

I'll need to implement asynchronous saving in a Core Data document-based application. My `NSDocument` subclass is patterned just like iOS' `UIManagedDocument` with a pair of `NSManagedObjectContext` instances, one for the main thread with a parent context for background saving.

The problem is that whenever I the document, the app always displays a prompt:

> The document ... could not be saved. The file has been changed by another application.

I wonder what is missing from my implementation? How can I make the dialog above go away whenever I save?

You can find my `NSDocument` subclass in this gist: https://gist.github.com/3652120

Comment: just checking you know about NSPersistentDocument ?

Comment: @hooleyhoop Yes, I know about `NSPersistentDocument`. It doesn't support async saving and file packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently cloning the functionality of `UIManagedDocument` isn't too hard. One caveat is to make sure that the `NSDocument`'s notion of the file's date is updated whenever the main thread's context is saved. The second caveat is to use the main thread managed object context's undo manager.

Refer to [Bringing Asynchronous Core Data documents to OS X](http://cutecoder.org/programming/asynchronous-core-data-document) for information on how to do this and sample `NSDocument` subclass code how to do it.